# What are these numbers in an assembly or file in a vdproj file?

Tags: .net, format, vdproj

```
{**9F6F8455-1EF1-4B85-886A-4223BCC8E7F7**}:**_03AB8A75D149B335EA5B97C256BF5342**"
        {
        "AssemblyRegister" = "3:1"
        "AssemblyIsInGAC" = "11:FALSE"
        "AssemblyAsmDisplayName" = "8:UILibrary, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86"
            "ScatterAssemblies"
            {
                "**_03AB8A75D149B335EA5B97C256BF5342**"
                {
                "Name" = "8:UILibrary.DLL"
                "Attributes" = "3:512"
                }
            }
        "SourcePath" = "8:UILibrary.DLL"
        "TargetName" = "8:"
        "Tag" = "8:"
        "Folder" = "8:**_03B2F8A0E94043BBA08EC194BFA35C4A**"
        "Condition" = "8:"
        "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
        "Vital" = "11:TRUE"
        "ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
        "Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
        "System" = "11:FALSE"
        "Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
        "SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
        "PackageAs" = "3:1"
        "Register" = "3:1"
        "Exclude" = "11:TRUE"
        "IsDependency" = "11:TRUE"
        "IsolateTo" = "8:"
        }
```

Those numbers inside the **, can anyone please tell me what they are and what they are for? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid) or in other words **Globally Unique Identifiers**. You'll find all the information you need if you click the link that will transfer you to Wikipedia article about 'em.

BTW: Microsoft's implementation is called UUID or **Universally Unique Identifier**. Arrogant? Maybe.